# How to read the same column from multiple files and collect it in an array

Tags: arrays, pandas, multiple-columns, read.csv

I have 9 csv files each containing the same number of columns (61) as well as the same column headers. The files are basically follows-up of each other. Each column belongs to a signal reading which has been recorded for a long period of time and hence divided into multiple files. I need to graph the collected data for every single column. To do that I thought I would read one column at a time from all files and store the data into an array and graph it against time. 
Since the data load is to much, system takes a reading every 5 seconds for a month, I want to read the data for every 30 mins which equals to reading 1 row per 362 rows.

I've tried plotting everything without skipping rows and it takes forever because of the data load.

file_list = glob.glob('*.csv')
cols = [0,1] # add more columns here

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in file_list:

```
df = df.append(
    pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\s+', header=None, usecols=cols),
    ignore_index=True,    
)
```

arr = df.values

This is what I tried to read only specific columns from multiple files but I receive this message: "Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: [1]"

Answer (score 0):

the command below will do a parallel read followed by a concatenation. Assuming `file_list` contains a list of files that can be read with `read_file` function below

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def read_file(file):
    return pd.read_csv(file)


pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())  # one worker per CPU. You can try other things
df = pd.concat(pool.map(read_file, file_list)
pool.terminate()
pool.join()
```